# coefficient of determination: absence of cross products

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

With regard to the coefficient of determination, why is the total variation equal to the sum of the explained variation and the unexplained variation and there are no cross-products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum(Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 &= \sum[(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)+( \hat{Y}_i-\bar{Y})]^2\\
                      &=\sum(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2 + \sum(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y})(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i) + \sum(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y})^2\\
&                     =\sum(Y_i - \hat{Y})^2+\sum(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y})^2 
\end{align}
because 
$$
\sum(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y})(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i) = \sum(\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y})e_i = \sum \hat{Y}_ie_i - \sum\bar{Y}e_i = 0 + 0=0.
$$

---

The last two assertions follow from the OLS construction 
$$
s(\beta) = \sum \left(Y_i - \beta_0- \sum \beta_jX_j\right)^2\\
s_{\beta_0}'(\hat{\beta}) =-2\sum \left(Y_i - \hat{\beta_0}- \sum \hat{\beta}_jX_j\right)=-2\sum e_i =0.
$$
For the first assertion, $\sum \hat{Y}_ie_i $ try to prove the orthogonality of $\hat{Y}$ and $e$ vectors in the simple regression model, then it is straightforward to extend it to $p$ number of $\beta$.

Comment: it is not clear why the cross products are zero.

\sum e_i = 0 \Rightarrow \sum \bar{Y_i}e_i = 0

why \sum \hat{Y_i}e_i = 0 ?

Comment: See edition of my answer

Comment: $
\hat{y_i} = x_i\beta
\newline
e_i = y_i - \hat{y_i} = y_i - x_i \beta
\newline
\Rightarrow
\newline
\sum \hat{y_i} e_i = \sum \left ( x_i \beta y_i - x_i \beta x_i \beta \right ) = \sum x_i \beta \left ( y_i - x_i \beta \right ) = \sum x_i \beta e_i = 
\newline
= \beta \sum x_i e_i = 0
\newline
since
\newline
s(\beta) = \sum \left ( y_i - x_i \beta \right )^2
\newline
s_{\beta}'\left ( \beta \right ) = 2 \sum \left ( y_i - x_i \beta \right )\left ( - x_i \right ) = 0
\newline
\Rightarrow
\newline
\sum x_i \left ( y_i - x_i \beta \right ) = \sum x_i e_i = 0
$

Comment: thank you so much. I'm not able to write formulas correctly but I think I was able to demonstrate the orthogonality of $\hat{Y}$ and $e$